# Is it possible to deploy a program from a key in a ledger?

Tags: solana-program, deploy

If it's not possible (or not practical), what are best practices for deployment security?

I think that deployment via another program (such as Realms) is probably not practical for most folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solana CLI help information lists using a hardware wallet keypair file by setting the keypair file path as `usb://ledger`

Specifically from the `solana program deploy --help` output:

```
--program-id <PROGRAM_ID>
            Executable program's address, must be a keypair for initial deploys, can be a pubkey for upgrades [default:
            address of keypair at /path/to/program-keypair.json if present, otherwise a random address], one of:
              * a base58-encoded public key
              * a path to a keypair file
              * a hyphen; signals a JSON-encoded keypair on stdin
              * the 'ASK' keyword; to recover a keypair via its seed phrase
              * a hardware wallet keypair URL (i.e. usb://ledger)
```

So I would think you can set any keypair file to be the `usb://ledger` key file should work

Comment: perfect, thanks, i also found this link here which allows you to specify the derivation key/location https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/hardware-wallets/ledger

Answer (score 0):

Using a Ledger pubkey to reserve a program address (program id), while possible, doesn't particularly make sense.  This keypair is only used once, during the initial deployment, then never needs to sign again.  There is no reason for it to be secure.

There are other roles regarding program deployment/management as well:

- Upgrade authority - this is the only role that really makes sense to secure
- Buffer authority - this is impractical as it must sign every buffer write transaction of which there are typically hundreds per deploy/upgrade operation.

Comment: yeah my question was about the upgrade authority, should have been more specific, thanks though

Comment: are the buffer authority and the upgrade authority the same by default?

Comment: new question, new post ;)